# Contact Form same page success

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to send an email with PHP and Ajax, the mailer is working but I know very little about Ajax, after reading a couple of pages of a book I have written a small piece of code and was hoping someone could point out where I am going wrong:

#### Here is my PHP:

```
<?php


$name =  ($_POST['name']);
$email =  ($_POST['email']);
$fsubject =  ($_POST['subject']);
$message = ("Name: ". $name . "\nEmail Address: " . $email . "\n\nMessage: " . $_POST['message']);


// Set Mail
$to = "emailaddress@fakeone.com";
$headers = 'emailaddress@fakeone.com' . "\r\n";
$subject = "{$fsubject}";
$body = "{$message}";


// Send Mail
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) 
{
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} 
else 
{
    echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}

?>
```

#### My HTML:

```
<div id="success" style="color:red;"></div>

<form action="" id="contactform" method="post">
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label>Your name *</label>
<input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your name." maxlength="100"     class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label>Your email address *</label>
<input type="email" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email address." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<label>Subject</label>
<input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter the subject." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<label>Message *</label>
<textarea maxlength="5000" data-msg-required="Please enter your message." rows="10"     class="form-control" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-loading-text="Loading...">
</div>
</form>
```

#### My AJAX:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#submit').click(function(){

        $.post("sendmail.php", $("#contactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
        $('#success').html(response);
        //$('#success').hide('slow');
            });
            return false;
        });

        });
    </script>
```

At the moment the same page just reloads, the desired outcome is just a subtle success or failure message appearing.

Any help would be welcome!

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: you need a div with `id="success"` in some where so that the `$('#success').html(response);` can access it for updating.

Comment: Oops, I didn't mean to miss that out! It's in there. Just above my contact form.

Comment: It doesn't look like your javascript is being called.  Try adding alerts after the ready, after the submit click, after the post, and on success.

Comment: In your HTML you have to take `action=''` out completely, otherwise the form will submit to itself. That, or change the `type=submit` to `type=button`.

Comment: Are you sure click event is fired?

Comment: @RyanWillis `return false` should prevent both. So no need to remove `action` or change the button.

Comment: @RyanWillis No luck - Just removed it. It's still just refreshing.

Comment: You probably have an error in your JS. Do you have more JS on that page? You also forgot to close the last div.

Comment: @putvande - Thanks, the Div closes outside the form. There is lots of JS on the page as it's bootstraped, using Parralax, JS Menu, google maps.

Comment: Seems there should be error/conflict on your page. What doeas your console log says. Because your code works in my localhost.

Comment: Check your browser javascript console for javascript errors. If it has lots of JS code that could be the cause. Even if your JS error is in another place it can cause JS execution to stop and so your onClick isn't executed

Comment: @DanDotNet you can't close a `div` outside the `form` that is opened inside the `form`.

Comment: Hi Guys, Thanks for the pointing out the obvious it was a conflict with another bit of JS. All sorted now, removed the conflict and it's worked. What a wally!

Comment: One more question. It's not triggering the form but not posting any of the data through to the PHP. Therefore I am getting blank emails. Any idea why?

Comment: Check my answer to bypass jquery ajax post to check if PHP is working correctly and variables are passed correctly

Comment: @AlfaTeK - It's all fine. It was running as a PHP script for some time straight from the HTML page. Now it needs to not reload basically.

Comment: in your PHP try var_dump($_POST) to see if data is coming there. jquery sure is sending them

Comment: @AlfaTeK, I am getting 'array(0) { }'

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet code seems to run just fine.
It must be an error either in other JS (check browser console, F12 in Chrome for example) or in your PHP.

Try this to see if ajax post fails:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#submit').click(function(){

        $.post("contact.php", $("#contactform").serialize(),  function(response) {
        $('#success').html(response);

            }).fail(function() {
                alert( "error" );
            });
            return false;
        });

        });
    </script>
```

Also, try to make sure PHP execution is fine, so remove all javascript and replace

```
<form action="sendmail.php" id="contactform" method="post">
```

Check the result of that page, it should be "Message successfully sent!".

Also, check a simple JS snippet of your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/CPtpk/

Please note that if you have another JavaScript code in your page that could be a cause for this problem. Even if your JS error is in another place it can cause JS execution to stop and so your onClick isn't executed and that's why you get your problem...

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this on the JS:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#contactform').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $.post("sendmail.php", $(this).serialize(),  function(response) {
            $('#success').html(response);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```