# Ajax not posting form data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I recently asked a question about executing a Send Mail script without a page reload and worked out what my problem was with my AJAX, that's all resolved. I now have an issue with the following:

When my form posts to my AJAX the script is executed, however the post data doesn't seem to be come through to the PHP script.

The link to my question is:     [Contact Form same page success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151695/contact-form-same-page-success).

#### Here is my PHP:

```
<?php


$name =  ($_POST['name']);
$email =  ($_POST['email']);
$fsubject =  ($_POST['subject']);
$message = ("Name: ". $name . "\nEmail Address: " . $email . "\n\nMessage: " . $_POST['message']);


// Set Mail
$to = "emailaddress@fakeone.com";
$header = 'From: contactus@fakeone.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: website@fakeone.com';
$subject = "{$fsubject}";
$body = "{$message}";


// Send Mail
if (mail($to, $subject, $body, $header)) 
{
    echo("<p>Message successfully sent!</p>");
} 
else 
{
    echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}

?>
```

#### My HTML

```
<div id="success" style="color:red;"></div>

<form action="" id="contactform" method="post">
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-6">
<label>Your name *</label>
<input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your name." maxlength="100"     class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
<label>Your email address *</label>
<input type="email" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter your email address." data-msg-email="Please enter a valid email address." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<label>Subject</label>
<input type="text" value="" data-msg-required="Please enter the subject." maxlength="100" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject">
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-md-12">
<label>Message *</label>
<textarea maxlength="5000" data-msg-required="Please enter your message." rows="10"     class="form-control" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-12">
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-loading-text="Loading...">
</div>
</form>
```

#### My AJAX

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('#submit').click(function () {

                $.post("sendmail.php", $("#contactform").serialize(), function (response) {
                    $('#success').html(response); 

                });
                return false;
            });

        });
    </script>
```

When I fill out the forms, nothing comes back it sends an empty email.

Any idea's why the post isn't working on this would be greatly appreciated. If I am breaking any rules by posting another question please let me know!

Regards,
Dan

Comment: Have a look at your browser's console to see if there are any errors or other information that might help to solve this.

Comment: event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead.

Comment: echo all variables before sending email

Comment: @AwladLiton - Hi Awlad, nothing back from Echoing...

Comment: all variable are empty?

Comment: Yes. Nothing is getting posted via Ajax, I have taken the AJAX out of the equation and it posts fine.

Comment: Not sure what's happening, any idea's?

Comment: Add a console.log($('#contactform').serialize()); to the script right after the click function and see what that returns. Also, name the form. I have seen some wonkiness when forms don't have names.

Comment: Hi Jay, what I am looking for in the log specifically?

Comment: You should see a key=value pair for each item being sent.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your PHP code. You've got a variable named *$headers*, but in your mail function you're using *$header*. A typo.

Comment: Thanks Oscar, Sorry it's not that. I copied the code wrong, it is header for both.

Comment: Updated how it actually is now!

Comment: Check the network panel of the developer tools in the browswer you're using. You'll be able to see what you're sending and what you are receiving from the server.

Comment: Thanks, Nothing different showing in the network panel. What am I looking for, I've submitted the script twice and can see its entering nothing like previously thought.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines from this -

```
$subject = "{$fsubject}";
$body = "{$message}";
```

to this -

```
$subject = $fsubject;
$body = $message;
```